# what action does "recommend deletion" perform?

Tags: support, low-quality-posts

I hope I'm not asking (again) a trivial question on meta.

When a high-rep user runs out of "delete" votes (or the reviewer doesn't have the "post delete vote" privilege, or the flagged question has a positive vote count), the "Delete" button of LQP turns into "Recommend Deletion".

I often use that without commenting (to avoid revenge downvotes, got my share of those). So if it's not to post/upvote an automatic comment, what effect does that button have ?

This is unclear. For example [that post](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/6714725) got 6 "recommend deletion", 1 "delete" and 2 "looks OK" and got deleted.

So what's the rule?

Comment: Cross-site dupe: [What does Recommend deletion button do in the Low Quality Review Queue?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/168554/242209)

Comment: Thanks. I did not think of searching in the master meta site

Comment: any way to close that "cleanly" and link to the original question? or should I just delete the question altogether?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre There is no way to close the question as a dupe.  We can either copy the answer here or delete the question or provide a unique answer.

Comment: @NathanOliver, please do not delete cross-site duplicates.