# Low Quality Post What is Recommend Deletion

Tags: discussion, review-queues, low-quality-posts

I'm a bit confused on what Recommend Deletion is and to what it counts towards.

In other Review queues you can vote to close, which counts towards your close votes flags.

Is Recommend Deletion a flag? 
Does this contribute to a users stats in anyways other than the review queue?

Comment: feels like a duplicate of this: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/353880/what-action-does-recommend-deletion-perform but no on-site answer